# in ping the replay and request take the same routes?

Tags: linux, windows, request, echo, ping

In `ping`  , is it the `replay echo` and `request echo` take the same routes ?
and why  ?
in other terms do reply messages take the reverse path of the request messages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *Ping* is in fact an ICMP packet either indicating a request or reply. I would say that the answer to your questions in general is No since there's no guaranty that the path from your host to the destination is the same as the path from the destination to your host. Normally, this depends on the current status of the Network, the routing protocol used by your ISP and many other parameters.

Any way the ping is intended to calculate the round-trip delay (RTT) between your host and the destination. Thus, if the packets are traversing the same path or not should be transparent to any application you are using.